# Integral of limit is limit of integral and is finite, so the integrals over subsets also match

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Can someone please assist me with this question?

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of non-negative measurable functions on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ that converge to $f$ pointwise. Suppose that 
$$\int_\Omega f \ \mathrm{d}\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\Omega f_n \ \mathrm{d}\mu < \infty$$ 
Then show that for any $A \in \mathcal{A}$
$$\int_A f \ \mathrm{d}\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A f_n \ \mathrm{d}\mu.$$
Trivially, I can use Fatou's lemma to show that $\int_A f \ \mathrm{d}\mu \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A f_n \ \mathrm{d}\mu$. But as for the reverse inequality, I'm not sure.